# circuit for phototransistor sound receiver

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, audio, phototransistor

I'd like to build a phototransistor receiver. I've tried different sample circuits (I'm not any good in circuit design) and would like to ask for assistance. I am looking for a circuit that is capable of different stages or adjustion of gain of 1-1000x as the phototransistor based on the incoming light intensity can create 0.1-100mA. I'd like to feed the amplified signal to a DAC(0-5V).

Here is a project which is doing something like what I need (w/o the adjustable gain option):
https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/s2017/projects/jalverio_Project_Final_Report.pdf

And a simpler one(I'd go for something like this):
https://personal.colby.edu/personal/b/bcshutt/alc6.html

Any ideas or references that I can use and learn from would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Always start with requirements. Sensitivity, bandwidth, etc. Your goal is too vague. Are you looking to accurate measure static light level? Or, just looking for changes in light level so you can trigger an event?

Comment: I'd like to detect changes in light level. The phototransistor is a PD333-3C or similar and the laser would be at 650nm wavelength.  As I'd like to detect sound frequency I need only 50-7kHz bandwith.